# How combine the same key twice and another one in vscode shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to setup the same `Add cursor up/down` shortcut from Pycharm: `alt alt up/down` in Visual Studio Code. I have seen this issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/5280 but it only covers `alt alt` and not combining that with another key. I have tried the following combinations:

```json
  {
    "key": "alt alt up",
    "command": "editor.action.insertCursorAbove",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt alt+up",
    "command": "editor.action.insertCursorAbove",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt alt up",
    "command": "editor.action.insertCursorAbove",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
```

And none of them seems to work. I'm on MacOs. Any idea if this is possible? I think it should be because you can do it in Pycharm.

Comment: I don't think it does, the double modifier key combo was added relatively recently and there was no mention of using it like that.

Comment: sad to hear that

Answer (score -2):

In Visual Studio Code you can just type (press the keys on the keyboard) when selecting a new shortcut

Comment: I know, but you cannot press alt twice

Comment: so just pick a new combination for that, something like ctrl+arrow-up

Comment: I don’t want another combination.